# How to make a new numeric type which can be cast to an enum in C#

Tags: c#, enums, interface, casting

I'm attempting to write a DWARF parser in C#. DWARF has the concept of multiple numeric types (`DW_FORM_data2`, `DW_FORM_data4`, `DW_FORM_data8`, `DW_FORM_sdata`, `DW_FORM_udata`) which may all be resolved to enum types. I'd love to make an `IConstant` which the aforementioned `DW_FORM_*` classes implement which you can cast to an enum (just as you can cast `ushort`, `int` etc. to an enum).

However, a cast operator is a static method, and I can't put that on an enum. How does one go about making a group of numeric types which can be converted to enums? One complicating factor is that the size (8-bits, 32-bits, etc.) of a `DW_FORM_udata` or `DW_FORM_sdata` number isn't defined until it's decoded.

Comment: Do you want to be able to cast to any `enum` ?

Comment: Why do you want to cast and not just have a method to do the conversion?

Comment: Yes. Any enum. Perhaps a method is the way to go. So just add a `ToEnum()` method on the interface? That might be the answer I'm looking for. Would you make `ToEnum` generic?

Comment: @DavidG How would a method convert to any available `enum` the way you can cast `int` to any `enum`?

Comment: It is the kind of thing you have to do in the C language because it doesn't guarantee the size of the built-in types.  Which burdens every library by having to declare their own type aliases, there are tens of thousands of ways to say "I'm using a 32-bit unsigned type".  I might be low-balling that.  They finally smelled the coffee and added stdint.h, too late for Dwarf.  Not a problem in C#, an UInt32 is always unsigned and always takes 4 bytes.  It has nothing to do with interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple interface (not sure `IConstant` is the best name):

```
public interface IConstant {
    TEnum ToEnum<TEnum>();
}
```

And then implement it in each of your numeric type classes, something like:

```
public TEnum ToEnum<TEnum>() {
    return (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), Value);
}
```

Then you can call it by specifying the `enum` type in the call:

```
var ev = data8.ToEnum<TestEnum>();
```

Without knowing the details of the classes, it is hard to say if you would be better off with an abstract class with a single implementation, if that is even possible.

Comment: This works very well in my case. Thanks. Especially since the the different "constant" types will be cast to different C# numeric types. DWARF puts them all in the "constant" class--that's why I called them that.